# How to improve efficiency of my find target function

Tags: c++, performance

I need to improve the efficiency of my program and, using the profiler, have narrowed the problem down to 2 key areas, but I am having trouble coming up with ways to make the program run better.

Based on my profiler's report, it seems to be telling me that my if functions are inefficient. Whats a better way to achieve a better result?

```
Character* FindAttackTarget() const
{
    float weakestHp = FLT_MAX;
    Character* weakestEnemy = nullptr;
    uint64_t weakestCharId = INT64_MAX;

    //Only attack characters that are within attack range
    auto& gameChars = m_pGame->m_gameCharacters;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < gameChars.size(); ++i)
    {
        auto& c = gameChars[i];
        if (Location.Dist(c.GetLocation()) <= AttackRange &&
            c.HP > 0 &&
            c.Team != Team)
        {
            //We want the weakest with the lowest ID number
            //this keeps consistent results when re-playing the same part of the game
            // (eg. after a load game)
            if (c.HP < weakestHp || (c.HP == weakestHp && c.ID < weakestCharId))
            {
                weakestEnemy = &gameChars[i];
                weakestHp = c.HP;
                weakestCharId = c.ID;
            }
        }
    }

    return weakestEnemy;
}
```

Comment: If it works, maybe post on [codereview.se]

Comment: Good point. Thank you.

Comment: Your linear search by itself cannot really be improved (possibly `Dist` in `SquareDist` to avoid square root, if you use it). You probably need to reorganize your data to not check against every character. Partition grid or maintaining HP order (to stop at first matching char) might help for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you do this frequently, consider maintaining another list, or perhaps a balanced tree of the characters - sorted by the criteria you're looking for.

In fact, you might have a master list of characters, and have multiple different views or indexes into that list, each optimal for some query about the relationships between them.

Relational Databases routinely do this with indexes into tables, even multiple tables to speed up queries that involve specific fields.  The idea is that as you add characters, the expense of making the index is low.  And you only add perhaps 1000 characters - index is built, but during game-play you may ask questions about the relationships many thousands of times.